# Behave run features in random order

Tags: python, python-behave

I have 10 features with 10 different step functions written in python using behave library.
They are all independent of each other, to show that i have to run them in random order. Right now behave is running them alphabetically with `behave -i` tag. Is there a built in function to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but I was having the same issue and found a solution.

There is no out-of-the-box support for a randomizing the feature files. However, the `behave` framework is written in a way that makes adding this behavior fairly easy.

I created a file `my_behave.py` in the project's root with the following content:

```py
import random
import sys

from behave.__main__ import Configuration, run_behave, Runner


class ShuffleRunner(Runner):

    def feature_locations(self):
        locations = super().feature_locations()
        random.shuffle(locations)
        return locations


def main():
    config = Configuration()
    return run_behave(config, runner_class=ShuffleRunner)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Then, instead of calling the `behave` command, do:

```bash
python my_behave.py
```

This also accepts the usual options. When using a [shebang](https://realpython.com/python-shebang/) and/or a shell alias you can replace the default `behave` command with your custom one altogether.

**Detailed explanation of the inner workings:**

When running the `behave` command, the `__main__.py` file in the behave library is executed. It contains a function `run_behave` which actually accepts a custom runner class. But this parameter stays unused.

So what we can do now is to import the `run_behave` function and hand it our own custom runner class.

Luckily, the logic for collecting the feature files is abstracted away in the `feature_locations` method in the `Runner` class. We can simply override this method and instead do the following:

- Do a super-call to get the feature locations.
- Shuffle these.
- Return as if nothing happened.

You can override as much methods as you want if you need more custom behavior.